# Cardview not showing properly in portrait mode?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm using androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0The design preview for my activity_main layout in Android Studio shows the layout perfectly... But when I try to run in my real device , it messed up in portrait mode.

[image]

Here is my code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@drawable/background" tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_marginTop="40dp" android:layout_marginRight="20dp"> 

<ImageView android:id="@+id/logo" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_width="90dp" android:layout_height="90dp" android:src="@drawable/circle" />

 </RelativeLayout>

 <GridLayout android:id="@+id/grid1" android:layout_marginTop="40dp" android:columnCount="2" android:rowCount="3" android:alignmentMode="alignMargins" android:columnOrderPreserved="false" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_columnWeight="1" android:layout_rowWeight="1" app:cardElevation="60dp" app:cardCornerRadius="12dp" android:layout_margin="12dp" > 

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="16dp" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

<ImageView android:src="@drawable/object" android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="80dp"> 
</ImageView>

 <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="12dp" android:fontFamily="casual" android:text="Object Detection" android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="18sp"> </TextView> </LinearLayout> </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView> **repeat the above cardview for the remaining 7 cards** . </GridLayout> </LinearLayout> </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your card view set `android:layout_width="0dp"` like code below

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/circle" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/grid1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="3"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:rowCount="3">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="60dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/object"></ImageView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:fontFamily="casual"
                        android:text="Object Detection"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp"></TextView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="60dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/object"></ImageView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:fontFamily="casual"
                        android:text="Object Detection"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp"></TextView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="60dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/object"></ImageView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:fontFamily="casual"
                        android:text="Object Detection"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp"></TextView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            **repeat the above cardview for the remaining 7 cards** .
        </GridLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```